# Prestashop 1.6: How to create and submit custom form using admin controller

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have been searching for documentation regarding this problem. But found no desired one.

I know how to load admin template using admin controller.
I have created a form with

```
<form action="{$link->getModuleLink('pushnotification', 'AdminPushNotification', [], true)|escape:'html'}" method="post">
```

Here "pushnotification" is my module name and "AdminPushNotification" is my admin controller name.

when I hit submit it goes to http://example.com/en/module/pushnotification/AdminPushNotification URL which is not a valid URL thus get 404 page

But I want to submit the form and stay in the same page.

I dont know how to submit and handle form submission in Admin Controller.

Thanks in advance

My module file structure:
pushnotification
    controllers
        Admin
            AdminPushnotification.php
Views
   templates
      admin
         pushnotificationform.tpl

My Admin Controller code:

```js
    <?php

class AdminPushNotificationController extends ModuleAdminControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()   {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();


        $smarty = $this->context->smarty;
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'msg' => "",
            'title' => ""
        ));
        $content = $smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'pushnotification/views/templates/admin/pushnotificationform.tpl');
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'content' => $this->content . $content
        ));
    }

    public function postProcess()
    {
        if (Tools::isSubmit('sendTokenMessage'))
        {
            $title = Tools::getValue('title');
            $msg = Tools::getValue('message');

            $content = $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'pushnotification/views/templates/admin/pushnotificationform.tpl');
            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'content' => $this->content . $content,
                'msg' => $msg,
                'title' => $title
            ));
        }
    }

    public function sendMessage($title,$msg)
    {

        $sql = " Select Token From Token";

        $result = DB::getInstance()->execute($sql);

        foreach($result as $row) {
            $message = array("title" => $title, "text"=> $msg);
            $message_status = send_notification($row["token"], $message);
        }
        return $message_status;
    }
}
```

and my pushnotificationform.tpl code:

```js
<div>
    {if $msg!=""}
        <p>{$msg}</p>
    {/if}
</div>
<form action="{$link->getAdminLink('pushnotification', 'AdminPushNotification', [], true)|escape:'html'}" method="post">
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px;" class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-lg-6">Title</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="title" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-lg-6">Message</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="sendTokenMessage" value="send" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$link->getModuleLink()` retrieves a link to a module front controller.

You need to use `$link->getAdminLink('AdminPushNotification')` to create a link to your admin controller.

**Edit:**

You are calling the `$link->getAdminLink()` method in wrong way.
All you need to do in your form is:

```
<form action="{$link->getAdminLink('AdminPushNotification')|escape:'htmlall':'utf-8'}" method="post">
```

`getAdminLink()` method is different from `getModuleLink()` as it accepts only one string parameter which is the name of your admin module controller  `AdminPushNotification`.

You can check the `classes/Link.php` class for various link generating methods and their parameters.

**Edit2:**

You are assigning content twice - in `postProcess()` and `initContent()` which throws out errors.

Use `postProcess()` to do some background work with inputs ie. your `send_message($title, $msg)` method or validation.

Use `initContent()` to set smarty variables/templates etc.

So I would refactor these two methods like this:

```
protected $msg = "";
protected $title = "";

public function postProcess()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('sendTokenMessage'))
    {
        // store inputs to object properties,
        // here they can be validated and reused in initContent()
        $this->title = Tools::getValue('title');
        $this->msg = Tools::getValue('message');

        // perhaps do some inputs validation here

        $this->send_message($this->title, $this->msg);
    }
}

public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();

    $smarty = $this->context->smarty;
    // msg and title variables must be assigned before fetching template
    // otherwise they are not recognized in template
    $smarty->assign(array(
        'msg' => $this->msg,
        'title' => $this->title
    ));
    $content = $smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'pushnotification/views/templates/admin/pushnotificationform.tpl');
    $smarty->assign(array(
        'content' => $this->content . $content
    ));
}
```

Of course also remember to escape `$msg` and `$title` in templates to protect against XSS and also sanitize strings to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: I have changed to $link->getAdminLink. Now getting 404 page. Actually can you give me some documentation about How to handle the form  submission in admin controller ?

Comment: public function postProcess()
    {
        if (Tools::isSubmit('sendTokenMessage'))
        {
            $title = Tools::getValue('title');
            $msg = Tools::getValue('message');

            $content = $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'pushnotification/views/templates/admin/pushnotificationform.tpl');
            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'content' => $this->content . $content,
                'msg' => $msg,
                'title' => $title
            ));
        }
    }

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is anything else but [this](http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-use-the-class-admincontroller-in-prestashop.html) but if you can show your entire controller code I might be able to help you further.

Comment: I have added the my file structure and my admin controller,  thank you @TheDrot

Comment: I've edited the answer after seeing your template html.

Comment: is my postProcess right ? now redirecting to blank page

Comment: @JahangirAlam Updated answer.